Выставление разных DSCP-отметок одного соединения
Есть следующая ситуация - одно соединение, по нему идет GTP-трафик, и для разных пакетов в поле DSCP нужно выставлять разные значения.
Есть проблема - используется версия ядра Linux < 3.10, которая не поддерживает такое выставление через стандартный сокетный интерфейс (попытка выполнить установку DSCP поля для пакета приводит к ошибке Invalid Argument). Сменить используемую версию ядра в данный момент не представляется возможным, потому что используется очень сложный софт, которому нужна именно такая версия ядра.
На сколько мне известно, DSCP-отметки можно выставлять через iptables, но я сомневаюсь, что через iptables можно выставлять разные отметки пакетам одного соединения.
Вопрос заключается в том, какие есть альтернативы?
